# Why won't componentWillReceiveProps() and shouldComponentUpdate() work on my ReactJS component?

Tags: reactjs, auto-update

I tried to set up communication between two component dynamically, but it's not working

After the first change, the data becomes `undefined`.

If anyone can help me with this problem I would appreciate it.
Data does not have to be transmitted this way, any way that works is okay.

```
class TableInput extends React.Component {
// eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-constructor
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
componentWillReceiveProps(newPrps){
    console.log("In")
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    console.log("updated");
    return true;
}

render() {
    return (
        <table className="table table-hover">
            <thead >
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">City</th>
                <th scope="col">Temp</th>
                <th scope="col">Weather</th>
                <th scope="col">Wind</th>
                <th scope="col">Today max</th>
                <th scope="col">Today min</th>
                <th scope="col">Pressure</th>
                <th scope="col">Clouds</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {this.props.cities.map(city => (
                <tr>
                    <td>{city.country}<img src={"https://www.countryflags.io/"+city.country+"/shiny/32.png"} alt={city-country}/></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>

    );
}
}
```

Parents component:

```
            <section id="services" className="services section-bg">
                <div className="container">

                    <div className="section-title">
                        <h3>CURRENT WEATHER</h3>
                    </div>
                    <TableInput cities={this.state.citiesCurrent}/>

                </div>
            </section>
```

Comment: Honestly just switch to functional components, class based components are such a mess, even they said so in their documentation

Comment: I could not see any `data` field/variable. How are you changing? I could not see the code to change anything. What kind of communication, sharing ?